# Cant get motion to start

Tags: camera, motion

I'm trying to set up raspberry pi for a timelapse. I have installed motion, but i cant get it to start.
I have tried to start it as a daemon. It seems to start, but when i run ps aux | grep motion there is no result. Also, when i try to stop it: sudo service motion stop, it just says that there is no process to kill.

When i disable daemon mode and try to run it from command line it just says: illegal instruction.

Any suggestions where to start looking? I have seen in the syslog, but no info about motion.

Answer (score 2):

You've installed the wrong version of `motion`. I'm assuming you're using Raspbian ?
You get the `Illegal Instruction` error when you've installed Debian ARMHF packages on Raspbian.

You've probably used the wrong repositories to install `motion`.
If you haven't done much work on the Pi so far, I'd re-flash Raspbian on, and then `apt-get install motion` again to get the correct version of `motion` installed.